# What do you call the part of a quantity that isn't the unit (e.g. the "5" in "5 inches")?

Tags: single-word-requests, measuring-units

I am thinking "value" is close, but I also want to use the word "value" for the whole thing.

> A value of 5 inches...

in which case the "value" should be broken into the "___" and the "unit".

An example sentence:

> In my software, to represent the different distances unambiguously, I store the unit along with the ___.

Comment: Quite. *…store the unit along with the quantity*.

Comment: Value should not be broken into anything. Value should be specified with appropriate units.

Answer (score 1):

According to "[What is the difference between quantity and unit](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-between-quantity-and-unit-609329)", in math and science the word is "*quantity*". So in `450kg`, the `450` is the quantity and unit is `kg`.

However, the [National Institute of Standard and Technology](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html) seems to use "*numerical value*".

Answer (score 0):

Value or amount are both fine. Mathematically, coefficient is also acceptable.

Comment: Uh… to me, that seems to add only confusion. *Value* and *amount* are both fine but neither is in any way necessary, nor in any way better that *quantity*.

If *coefficient* were acceptable how would that work? Would it be a *coefficient of length* or what, please?